# c#: adding two big integers gives wrong result

Tags: c#, arithmetic-overflow

So I have a code that adds two integers and prints the result:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter number: ");
int intTemp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
long sum = intTemp + 5;
Console.WriteLine($"sum is : {sum}");
```

But if in the console I will put the maximum value for the int type, I won't get an exception, but the result is wrong, even if I am saving the result in a long variable. Here is the output:

```
enter number:
2147483647
sum is : -2147483644
```

But if the sum variable is a long, why I am getting the wrong result?

Comment: Because `intTemp + 5` is still an `int`, and *then* it is assigned to a `long`. You can use `intTemp + 5L`. There should be a duplicate but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The add operator doesn't know (nor should it) *where* you intend to store it's result, it's type or size, etc.

Comment: If you want to see it crash and burn, try `long sum = checked(intTemp + 5);`. The result of adding two `int`s is still an `int`, even if you ultimately assign it to a `long`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so you're saying that everywhere I am adding two numbers, in order to be 100% sure that I'm getting the right result, I need to cast one to long (assuming that I save the result in a long variable)?

Comment: Or `long intTemp = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not of type `long`. It is of type `int` and afterwards it is converted to a long in order to assign it to a variable of type `long`.

That is needed to do, it is the following:

```
long sum = (long)intTemp + 5;
```

or

```
long sum = intTemp + (long)5;
```

Doing either of the above, since the one operand is of type (long), after conversion, the other would be converted also to long, in order the two values to can be added and the result would be stored to the `sum` variable.

Comment: so you're saying that everywhere I am adding two numbers, in order to be 100% sure that I'm getting the right result, I need to cast one to long (assuming that I save the result in a long variable)?

Comment: Essentially that I try to say is that when you expect the result of the addition of two int to be a number that cannot be represented by an int and it can be represented by a long, to convert one or another operand to long and an addition between two long to be performed instead the addition between two int.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the int "intTemp" to a long before, because the sum only gets cast to a long after the calculation is complete

Answer (score 0):

The key is like already mentioned that you need to convert one of the values to `long` to be able to retain the correct value as otherwise the result value is already corrupted before it is assigned to `long`. I would like to suggest that you can use `MaxValue` in these numeric types to make the calculation memory friendly if that is where you will use it for calculations. `int` takes 32 bits and `long` takes 64 bits. If the result of the calculation is still an `int` then you can save 32 bits of storage till you really need it. In your example you could do

```
if (int.MaxValue - 5) < intTemp ) // it means the value will go above int range if add 5
{
  // Make conversion to target type before the operation
}else{ 
  // the value will still be in int range
}
```

You can use the appropriate storage type for the result then. It can become quite memory efficient if you are storing large number of results and then using them for further calculations. Hope it helps.